# GPS Python Module Error

Tags: python, gps, raspberry-pi, gpsd

I'm trying to use [this script](http://www.danmandle.com/blog/getting-gpsd-to-work-with-python/) on an rpi. If gpsd is running and I run the script from the linked blog post, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/zzz/Timelapse/staticgps.py", line 29, in <module>
    gpsp = GpsPoller() # create the thread
  File "/home/zzz/Timelapse/staticgps.py", line 19, in __init__
    gpsd = gps.gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE) #starting the stream of info
NameError: global name 'gps' is not defined
```

Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks!!

Edit: Here is my script as requested. It is a direct copy/paste from the link.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# Written by Dan Mandle http://dan.mandle.me September 2012
# License: GPL 2.0

import os
from gps import *
from time import *
import time
import threading

gpsd = None #seting the global variable

os.system('clear') #clear the terminal (optional)

class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        global gpsd #bring it in scope
        gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE) #starting the stream of info
        self.current_value = None
        self.running = True #setting the thread running to true

    def run(self):
        global gpsd
        while gpsp.running:
            gpsd.next() #this will continue to loop and grab EACH set of gpsd info to clear the buffer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gpsp = GpsPoller() # create the thread
    try:
        gpsp.start() # start it up
        while True:
            #It may take a second or two to get good data
            #print gpsd.fix.latitude,', ',gpsd.fix.longitude,'  Time: ',gpsd.utc

            os.system('clear')

            print
            print ' GPS reading'
            print '----------------------------------------'
            print 'latitude    ' , gpsd.fix.latitude
            print 'longitude   ' , gpsd.fix.longitude
            print 'time utc    ' , gpsd.utc,' + ', gpsd.fix.time
            print 'altitude (m)' , gpsd.fix.altitude
            print 'eps         ' , gpsd.fix.eps
            print 'epx         ' , gpsd.fix.epx
            print 'epv         ' , gpsd.fix.epv
            print 'ept         ' , gpsd.fix.ept
            print 'speed (m/s) ' , gpsd.fix.speed
            print 'climb       ' , gpsd.fix.climb
            print 'track       ' , gpsd.fix.track
            print 'mode        ' , gpsd.fix.mode
            print
            print 'sats        ' , gpsd.satellites

            time.sleep(5) #set to whatever

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): #when you press ctrl+c
        print "\nKilling Thread..."
        gpsp.running = False
        gpsp.join() # wait for the thread to finish what it's doing
    print "Done.\nExiting."
```

Comment: Difficult to tell without more info. However, the link you posted seems to `from gps import *` and it looks like you either want to `import gps` and use `gps.gps` or just use `gps` if you've done the `from gps import *`

Comment: what more info would be required to debug? On the script, it just uses gps. This used to work, but has now stopped, so I'm guessing something happened on the backend but just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What are the imports for this python file?

Comment: @mh00h: it would help tremendously if you posted the *full* source code of *your copy* of the script here ([edit] your question to add it). If it used to have `gps` but you changed it because it stopped working, please tell us what error you get when you run the code *as written in that article*.

Comment: Updated! If also helpful to someone, I can open a shell, run "python," then "import gps" with no errors reported. I have also tried reinstalling python-gps and gpsd to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't copy the code correctly; linked page has this line:

```
gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE) #starting the stream of info
```

Note that it's just `gps()`, not `gps.gps()`; at the top of the script all names from the `gps` module are imported into the current namespace, making the `gps()` a local name.

Make sure you *do* have the statement `from gps import *` at the top of your script, from the error message it appears that you did not import it correctly (the `NameError` indicates that there is *nothing* named `gps` imported in your script).

Answer (score 3):

If someone stumbles here with the same problem, it is because your script file is named gps.py. Just rename it to something else, and the import will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace WATCH_ENABLE with 1, and it works.
I'm not sure why this constant is not exposed (newbie) - it is declared in client.py of the gps module

Answer (score 0):

Not only does naming your script gps.py cause gps to not be defined, you also can't name it gps1.py. Rename it to something like mygps.py